# Azure Cost Management Export : Is it possible to change the time at which an export is made

Tags: azure, cost-management

I use the export function to retrieve the cost data of one of my subscriptions.

However, I would like to change the time at which the export of the data is done.

Is this possible?

Thanks In Advance,

Charline

Read the documentation but there is no information

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't possible to set the time of the export. Daily is the least granularity that is provided for the export.

Comment: @SwathiDhanwada I think that is the answer

Comment: @Charline , what is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to set the time of the export. Daily is the least granularity that is provided for the export.